# NSOutlineView bindings through a NSArrayController

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nsoutlineview

I have a application which plays songs (tracks) with a structure like this (the [] brackets represend 'a list of'):

```
    SidebarController (NSObject)
      SidebarContentController (NSArrayController)
            [
                ListController (NSArrayController)
                    [
                        TrackModel (NSObject)
                    ]
            ]
```

I am using bindings in the InterfaceBuilder. As long as I had this structure everything was fine and I was able to bind the contents of a NSTableView to the SidebarController with: `self.sidebarContentController.selection.arrangedObjects`

Now I wanted to use a NSOutlineView instead because I wanted to show Playlists which the user will be able to open and play. So the structure looks like this now:

```
    SidebarController (NSObject)
      SidebarContentController (NSArrayController)
            [
                ListController (NSTreeController)
                    [
                        PlaylistModel (NSObject)
                            [
                                TrackModel (NSObject)
                            ]               
                    ]
            ]
```

But now I can not bind the NSOutlineView with
`self.sidebarContentController.selection.arrangedObjects` because when I start the application I get an exception:

```
    *** -[NSProxy doesNotRecognizeSelector:_mutatingNodes] called!
```

It works well when I try a simple structure like:

```
    ListController (NSTreeController)
        [
            PlaylistModel (NSObject)
                [
                    TrackModel (NSObject)
                ]               
        ]
```

then I can bind it with `self.arrangedObjects` on the ListController and the NSOutlineView shows all the playlists and the tracks. But I really need the SidebarContentController because I have not only one list of playlists but several.

Any Ideas what is going wrong? Here is a screenshot of the application so you understand why I need the SidebarContentController:

[image: Screenshot with sidebar]

I need the NSTableView to become a NSOutlineView to be able to show a tree structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the source of your problem is the use of controllers in what is essentially your model. As expressed in your structure diagrams, and assuming "list of" equates to an array, you have:

```
SidebarContent (NSArrayController)
    List (NSArrayController)[]
        Track (NSObject)[]
```

where instead you should have:

```
SidebarContent (NSArray)
    List (NSArray)[]
        Track (NSObject)[]
```

with controller objects that bind each view (two tableviews and a custom view; thus two NSArrayController's and perhaps an NSObjectController) to the appropriate content in your model (the second NSArrayController's content depending on the selection of the first).

At that point, you can visualize adding another layer to your model (List's of Playlist's?), substituting an NSOutlineView for the second NSTableView, and replacing the second NSArrayController with an NSTreeController.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I begin to understand. I will try to implement that approach.